# Head/Neck Rigging Problem

Tags: rigging

I'm having difficulty fixing a problem with the head/neck bones on a character I'm working on. I modified the character "Elaine" (a .blend that I downloaded from BlendSwap)

Elaine.blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32132

in order to create a new character "Maria":

Maria.blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32133

In the process of making my modifications, I accidentally deleted the "head" bone in Maria's rig (unfortunately, I didn't realize I'd deleted it right away). By carefully inspecting the two rigs, I recreated the head bone in Maria's rig, and parented the bones as they are in the Elaine rig.

The repaired rig almost works. When I rotate the head bone around the global x-axis, the head moves in the same way as in the Elaine rig. However, when I rotate the bone around the global z-axis, her head doesn't rotate horizontally, instead it just twists.

Here is the correct behaviour (with the head bone highlighted):

[Elaine with head bone highlighted http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=78534](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=78534)

And here is the problematic behaviour:

[Maria with head bone highlighted http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=78535](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=78535)

Is it possible for me to fix this rig or do I need to start over? I would greatly appreciate any rig-debugging tips other users could offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken constraint on the bone named : DEF_head (in the last bone layer of the armature).

[image]

Just select the bone named "head" in the "copy rotation" constraint.

[image]

Comment: it would be awesome when you could explain how you found this.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks. Along the lines of stacker's remark, I have a follow-up question: I think the original author of Elaine.blend might have used rigify. If I had known more about rigify, would I have been able to figure this problem out on my own?

Comment: I just assumed by experience that there would be another layer of bone hierarchy under the control one (usually a DEF_ or a MEC_, ...) and look into it if a constraint was broken. I narrowed my research around head bones as this is where the problem seemed to be and found the problem that way. Unfortunately Blender doesn't provide an easy way to display links (or broken links) between bones and objects (as I know of) but this one was fortunately quick to find.